# Mockito : Mocking and returning a different type value

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Is it possible to return a different type using when-return in mockito.

my function

```
m.findDocument(id)
```

returns a document based on `id` which I am converting to string for further processing.
But, for testing I am fetching the string from a id file. So, effectively I want that string to be returned when the function is called like below :

`when(m.findDocument(id)).thenReturn('that_string_from_id_file');`

Since, one is of document type and other of String, is there way in mockito I can do the same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thing is: using a mocking framework doesn't change the Java language.

When the signature of a method is `public Foo bar()` - then even when calling `bar()` on a **mocked** object, that method has to return an instance of Foo. You can't use mocking to silently change the declared return type of a method.

But of course, you can do:

```
Document mockedDocument = mock(Document.class);
DocumentFinder mockedFinder = mock(DocumentFinder);

when(mockedFinder.findDocument(id)).thenReturn(mockedDocument);
when(mockedDocument.getSomeInfo()).thenReturn("that string");
```

But please note: you would only *mock* that Document instance in case you can't  use a "real" Document instance. Your goal should be to *only* use mocking where it is impossible/too-hard without dealing with mocks.

Answer (score 0):

No. Depending on whether you use when+thenReturn or doReturn/doAnswer, you'll either get a compilation error or a ClassCastException.

What you can do is return a mock document from the method, and then return the test string when the mock is 'converted'.

Comment: Thanks. Second part seems confusing though !